# Gambler's Ruin Problem - Explanation needed for the start of the proof for the absorbtion probability

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I've been reading the textbook called `Introduction To Probability` by Dimitri P. Bertsekas, John N. Tsitsiklis and I have the following question regarding the proof of the absorbtion probability of the Gambler's ruin problem.

Given

- Transition probability to next state is `p` in the case of a win
- Transition probability to previous state is `1-p` in the case of a loss

$$a_0=0$$
$$a_i = (1-p)(a_{i-1}) + pa_{i+1} \hphantom{......}  i = 1,..,m-1$$
$$a_m = 1$$

To solve the equations, the book starts off by saying:

`Let us write the equations for the` $a_{i}$ `as :`

$$(1-p)(a_i -a_{i-1}) = p(a_{i+1} - a_{i}), \hphantom{...............} i=1,....,m-1$$

**My question**

What is the logic for the equation above?

Comment: What do you mean?  Do you not understand how to derive the equation?  Or do you not understand why the author wants to put it in that form?

Comment: I don’t understand why the author wants to put it in that form.

Comment: Well, try defining $b_i=a_{i+1}-a_i$.  I imagine this is what the author does; keep reading.

Comment: I did read it. My question again, is why is this **initial** statement true? i.e. why is the (probability of losing) * (difference between current state and previous state absorption probability)  = (probability of winning) * (difference between next state and current state absorption probability) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
a_i&= (1-p)(a_{i-1}) + pa_{i+1}\\
a_i-pa_{i+1}&=(1-p)(a_{i-1})\\
a_i-pa_{i+1}-(1-p)a_i&=(1-p)(a_{i-1})-(1-p)(a_i)\\
p(a_i-a_{i+1})&=(1-p)(a_{i-1}-a_i)\\
p(a_{i+1}-a_i)&=(1-p)(a_i-a_{i-1})
\end{align}$$